# Как замаппить значение поля к значениям из списка?

Tags: java, java-stream

У меня есть класс объект1, в котором есть id и лист класса объект2. Мне надо сопоставить значения объект2.id с объект1.id. Чтобы на выходе получилось что-то подобное.

```
public Map<UUID, UUID> getMapped(List<Object1> object1List) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public Map<Long, List<Object1>> getMapped(List<Object1> object1List) {
  return  object1List.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Object1::getId));

}
```